# Consul on k8s via Helm: Client and server pods cannot be scheduled on the same node

Tags: kubernetes, consul

According to consul, if choosing to expose the k8s consul servers to the LAN so LAN vm's can register with k8s Consul: [this needs to be done](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-k8s/blob/ccabee44129e0dc5b361977ae9cea35124838af4/charts/consul/values.yaml#L839)

```yaml
server:
  enabled: true
  exposeGossipAndRPCPorts: true
  ports:
    serflan:
      port: 9301
```

The switch to port `9301` is done so not colide with *agent pod* that's running on the same node as the *server pod*.

Which makes sense: as we're moving the server serflan to a different port, to avoid collision with the client pod's serflan port.

When doing so however, *only one of the two* pods gets actually scheduled, while the other:

```bash
0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports
```

If anyone has succeeded with running server and client Consul pods on the same node - or another solution that enables having a consul daemonset on each k8s node, please share your idea, thank you.